# How can I increment a counter in a binary search tree?

Tags: c, hashtable, binary-search-tree, counter

I have a list of numbers in a bst and I need to count how many times the program has the access to every single number and print it

```
enter 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#define HASHSIZE 153

typedef struct tree
{
int key;
int count;
struct tree *dx;
struct tree *sx;
struct tree *parent;
} node;


int Insertion(node **T, node *z)
{
node* y = NULL;
node* x = *T;
// int i=1;


while ( x != NULL )      
{
    y = x;
    if ( z->key < x->key)                          
    {
        x = x->sx;
       // x->count=i;    I DON'T KNOW HERE
    } else if ( z->key > x->key)
    {
        x = x->dx;           

    } else
    {

        return -1;  
    }
 }
 z->parent = y;

 if ( y == NULL ) *T = z;
 if ( (y != NULL) && (z->key < y->key) ) y->sx = z;
 if ( (y != NULL) && (z->key > y->key) ) y->dx = z;

   return 0;
 }

 int main(void)
 {
   FILE *fp;
   fp = fopen("data.txt","r");
   node *x = NULL;
   int search;

   hashtable = (hash *) malloc(HASHSIZE * sizeof(hash));   
   for (i = 0; i<HASHSIZE; i++) hashtable[i].head = NULL;

   while (!feof(fp))
   {
     fscanf(fp, "%d\t", search);
     if ( Search(hashtable[H(search)].head, search)==NULL )   
        {
            x = NewNode(search);
            Insertion( &hashtable[H(x->key)].head, x);
        }       
   }

  //Here there's also the node elimination but it's not important right now

  fclose(fp);
  return 0;
  }
```

My problem is printing the number of times that a number compare in a file.

I put down there NewNode, Search and H function

```
//  HASH  //
typedef struct _hash    
{
    node *head;
} hash;

hash *hashtable = NULL;


int H(int key)  
{
return (key % HASHSIZE);
}



//  NEWNODE //

node* NewNode(int z)
{
  node* temp; 
  temp = (node*) malloc( sizeof(node) );
  temp->key = z;
  temp->sx = NULL;
  temp->dx = NULL;
  temp->parent = NULL;

return temp;
}



// SEARCH //
node* Search(node *x, int k)
{
  while ( (x != NULL) && (k != x->key) )
  {
    if ( k < x->key )  
    {
        x = x->sx;
    }
     else             
    {
        x = x->dx;
    }
  }
  return x;
 }

 // TOP //

 int Top(int a, int b)
 {
  if (a>b) return a;
  return b;
 }

 // MIN //

 node* Min(node *x)
 {
  while (x->sx != NULL) x = x->sx;
  return x;
 }

 // MAX //
  node* Max(node *x)
  {
   while (x->dx != NULL) x = x->dx;
   return x;
  }

  // NEXT //
  node* Next(node *x)
  {
   if (x->dx != NULL)
       return Min(x->dx);
   node *y = x->parent;
   while ( y != NULL && x == y->dx ){
    x = y;
    y = y->parent;
   }
    return y;
  }

 //  HEIGHT //

 int Height(node *x)
 {
  if (x == NULL)
    return 0;
   return( 1 + Top( Height(x->sx), Height(x->dx) ));
 }

 // DECANT //

 void Decant(node **T, node *u, node *v)
 {
    if ( u->parent == NULL)
    *T = v;
    if ( u->parent != NULL  &&  u == u->parent->sx )
    u->parent->sx = v;
    if ( u->parent != NULL  &&  u == u->parent->dx )
    u->parent->dx = v;
    if ( v != NULL)
    v->parent = u->parent;
 }

 // DELATE //
 void Delate(node **T, node *z)
 {
    node *y;
    if ( z->sx == NULL )
    Decant(T, z, z->dx);
    if ( (z->sx != NULL) && (z->dx == NULL) )
    Decant(T, z, z->sx);
    if ( (z->sx != NULL) && (z->dx != NULL) )
    {
      y = Min(z->dx);
      if (y->parent != z){
        Decant(T, y, y->dx);
        y->dx = z->dx;
        y->dx->parent = y;
    }
    Decant(T, z, y);
    y->sx = z->sx;
    y->sx->parent = y;
   }
   free(z);
  }
```

Thx everyone!

Comment: It is off topic but please see [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong). It is better as `while(fscanf(fp, "%d", &search) == 1)` and no need of the `\t` because it is usually ignored (except when `%c` is present somewhere). Please note your mistake the the missing `&`.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding you. Try writing a list of operations you want happening during a search, or pseudo-code.

Comment: @WeatherVane thx so much! But right now I really need to fix the problem of counting. Can ya help me?

Comment: @kabanus The code is correct, no problem with the node insertion and so on. I really need to understand how to fix the problem of counting.

Comment: Your code does not compile with numerous errors and warnings. Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. Show some examples of the input, the expected output, and the actual output.

Comment: Also, even if it does work, I don't understand what your goal is. What exactly does "number of times that a number compare in a file" mean? when do you want to print/return this count?

Comment: I have a huge file with numbers and they repeat each other randomly. For example 50 numbers that repeat themselves a lot of times. I need to know the number that appear more and print ONLY the counter (If the number 5, that is the more frequent appear 65 times, it has to print "65")

Comment: Why do you need a tree for that? If the largest number is not great, a simple count array would do?

Comment: @WeatherVane 'cause the problem is with bst.